# Ebike throttle not working

Tags: electric-bike

Hi members friend got a dohiker ebike off ebay got it went for a ride came home and everything was fine...
plugged it in to charge and then just stopped working pedal assist works and walking mode works but when to turn the throttle nothing won't work ..
I had a friend come look at it tonight he bypassed the throttle an nothing ..  its very strange[image]

Comment: Needs more information  - make/model of the controller would be a minimum. Unfortunately there is not a lot of experience on this SE with EBikes so we will probably struggle to answer even a well formed question.

Comment: Dohiker ebike it is I've also added a picture of the bike on post also why the down vote I'm still learning the full ways of this site.Encourage ppl not discourage...thanks regardless.

Comment: Consider that the throttle doesn't work like you expect.  Its not a "valve" for power where bypassing would make any difference  Instead, it will be signalling the computer/controller to adjust the widths of PWM in the three separate power wires.  (yes it will be a 3 phase AC motor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Id check out all the connections firstlt then id check for any breaks in the wiring as with it being a foldup bike ive heard of the wiring being caught/streched when folding down etc it could be a simple cause as this if not it almost definitley looks like a failing on the throttle mechanism to me

Answer (score 1):

the wiring is damaged or your brake system is stuck. Take it out to the repair shop

Comment: Surely a stuck brake system wouldn't produce the quoted symptoms.  Walking mode wouldn't function properly for example.

Comment: I agree with chenmunka about the brake system being stuck surely the other modes would be compromised.